# Получить атрибут от тэга li

Tags: python, html, bs4

Проблема в том, что я не могу получить атрибут `itemprop` из элемента `li`. Постоянно выбрасывается исключение, говорящее о том, что атрибуты `attrs` и `get` не существуют для `NaviagatebleString`. Попробовал получить так: `li["itemprop"]` но тоже выбрасывался исключение `KeyError`, что его не существует. Вот HTML код:

```html
<ul>
    <li itemprop="name">User</li>
    <li itemprop="date">2012</li>
</ul>
```

Вот мой Python код:

```py
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("index.html", "html.parser")
ul = soup.find("ul")

for li in ul:
    print(li["itemprop"])
```

Comment: Вам же код говорит, мы не существуем))

Comment: Надо убрать переводы строк `if li != '\n': print(li["itemprop"])`